# "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" not found and cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, zxing

When following [this tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/12/tutorial-65-implement-barcode-scanner-using-zxing-in-android/), I have imported the library by putting this into gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.1.0'
compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.1.0'
```

However when I paste the Activity in the manifest e.g. :

```
<activity
   android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I get an error "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" not found and cannot be resolved. Has anyone else tried implementing this in AS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is not in `core` or `android-integration`. It's in `android/`, but this is not an artifact and not library to be embedded.

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial, clearly wrote that mark the android project as a Library after that add into your own project.